# How to prevent redirecting # to %23 by proxy reverse proxy in Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have added Proxy rule

```
ProxyPass /sample http://11.11.11.11:8080/some1/#/some2
ProxyPassReverse /sample http://11.11.11.11:8080/some1/#/some2
```

But Apache redirecting `#` to `%23` like `www.domain.com/sample%23/some2`

How to prevent this redirect?

Comment: I have formatted the rules as code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nocanon` keyword to pass the "raw" URL path, as described in [`ProxyPass` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

```
ProxyPass /sample http://11.11.11.11:8080/some1/#/some2 nocanon
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with your suggestions.Redirect issue # to %23 fixed but its throwing 404 error.